# Session doesn't save when headering to another page

Tags: php, session, header

I've got a 'shoppingcart' page and if they modify any values there and then click on 'order' i want the session to actually store the information before i header to the next page, however it seems that the $_SESSION variable does not save it before starting.

I have tried the following:
Solution 1:

```
$_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = $winkelwagen;
    session_write_close();
header("Location: checkout.php");
```

Solution 2:

```
$_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = $winkelwagen;
header("Location: checkout.php");
        exit();
```

However, neither of these seem to work for me, i have tried looking at the following stackoverflow topics too:
[PHP: session isn't saving before header redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968752/php-session-isnt-saving-before-header-redirect)
[Header Not Working With Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015666/header-not-working-with-sessions)

however neither of these work, this is my code:

```
$header = false;
if(isset($_POST['moveForward'])) {
    foreach($winkelwagen as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($_POST['aantal' . $val['artnr']])) {
            if (isset($_POST['verpakking' . $val['artnr']])) {
                $verpakking = $_POST['verpakking' . $val['artnr']];
                $aantal = intval($_POST['aantal' . $val['artnr']]);

                if ($val['amount'] !== $aantal) {
                    $val['amount'] = $aantal;
                    $winkelwagen[$key]['amount'] = $aantal;
                }
                if ($val['verpakking'] !== $verpakking) {
                    $val['verpakking'] = $verpakking;
                    $winkelwagen[$key]['verpakking'] = $verpakking;
                }
                $header = true;
            }
        }
    }
    $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = $winkelwagen;
    session_write_close();
    if($header) {
        header("Location: checkout.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you or your framework call [session_start](http://php.net/session_start) before using the session?

Comment: Yes, in our header.php that we include, we have a session_start.

Comment: Are you sure  $_SESSION['winkelwagen'] = $winkelwagen; line is running ? because you have several if condition and loops , check this

Comment: [This code](http://codepad.org/gDGfO6aB) works in a `php -S localhost:8080 ./raw.php` environment. That means session can survive after a redirection. Should be other issue than session.

Comment: It works perfectly if i don't redirect the page though @KoalaYeung

Comment: My code snippet works perfectly redirecting the page through. So probably not the issue of session handling itself. I suggest you should reduce your code for debug. Or build up from my snippet step-by-step to find out what's wrong.